# Array of "short" holds a 32bit value

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a strange one:

I have an `Int16` array.
I've uses `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy into it 8 bytes from a byte array.
After the copy - the 3rd element of the `UInt16` array holds a 32Bit value.

```
Int16[] max17261_results = new Int16[4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(response, 0, max17261_results, 0, 8);
```

`response` is an initialized byte array larger than `max17261_results`.

How? Why?

[image]

Comment: 8 is "count" parameter, not the number of bytes.

Comment: from MSDN:count
Int32
The number of bytes to copy.

Comment: It's displaying the short with decimal value `-24582` as hex integer. The debugger has converted the short to an int before displaying it. The data in the array itself will be `9ffa`

Comment: If you managed to store a 32-bit value into 16 bits, you should apply for the Nobel prize. :-)  The sign bit was expanded to 32 bit by the debugger display.

Comment: This is arguably a bug in the debugger; it makes zero sense to display a `short` value as an `int` and then only for negative values (because, as the positive values show, it knows full well to format things with 4 hex digits otherwise).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Agreed, the behaviour is somewhat stupid.